# How can I search random variables that I put into the code? Python

Tags: python, variables

**I want if to be able to pick a random one out of 50 variables that I put into my program, and I am also removing the '.csv' file** Im currently working on a small project of mine to have a little bit of fun. I want to be able to pick at random 10 variables (lets say food). I want to put in an input such as "random" then it will come up with a random variable, but it has to be out of the variables that I put into the code so it has certain name i.e "Salad". 
I have this so far (menu is not complete) just need a nudge to the right direction:

```
def main():
    print("Hello and Welcome to the 'Say When' program")
    my_data = load("saywhen.csv")

    print("1:Priamry\n2:Secondary\n3:FirstGag\n4:SecondGag")
    choice= (input("What would you like to search?: ")
    if choice == '1':
        print("Ok")
        search_prim(my_data)

    elif choice == '2':
        print("This is going well")
        search_sec(my_data)

    elif choice == '3':
        print("This is going smooth")
        search_FirstGag(my_data)

def search_prim(data):
    print("\nYou are searching for a Primary ")
    while 1:
        prim = (input("Primary: "))

        if prim = "random"
```

Comment: By random variable did you mean one of the variables declared in your program ?

Comment: Yes I mean that I can add a list into my program such as **"salad"** and I have about 40-50 of them, then my program chooses from that 40-50 and prints a random one.

Comment: This seems like an interesting problem. I just edited the title of your question to make it more obvious. Why not put the variables in a list then sample a random variable. thesquid24 pretty much answers it bellow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choosing from random is easily done in python via the `random.choice()` method.

if you define your available options in a set or a list, you can have your program choose randomly from them like this:

```
import random
choices = set(["salad", "steak", "soup"])
rand_choice = random.choice(choices)

# do stuff with the choice
```

It seems like your code is almost there, just add something similar to the above to get the random choice that you are looking for

Comment: When adding this to an empty file, it shows an error on **line 3**. I don't know how to fix this. Also I added it into my code after option **1** which is to search for primary. It says _Invalid Syntax_ for the colon I added ':' Any help?

Comment: It worked now, great! Just needed to add a bracket before random.choice. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

It's not a very clean idea to try and manipulate variables using input, but maybe you could look into a dictionary, with strings as the keys.

```
import random

dic = { }
dic['salad'] = 'tomato'
dic['potato'] = 'gravy'

return dic[random.choice(dic.keys())]
```

Comment: Error : _Unexpected EOF while parsing_ Any help?

Comment: There's a `]` missing. Also, this method is bad as one should use `random.choice` to select a random element from a collection - getting a random int and then selecting the element with that index is needlessly complicated.

Comment: @l4mpi I agree, `random.choice` slipped my mind. Feel free to update my answer.